# How can i rewrite react-method with setState and callback using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

I have a react component that contains the method with setState with a callback. I need to rewrite it to hooks. Please tell me how can i rewrite this method ?

```
 beforeSubmitModal = action => (args) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
      selectedMenuItem: null,
      companyCodeModal: {}
    }, () => action(args));
  };

const onDeleteCode = (id) => {
    dispatch(actions.deleteCode.request({ codeId: id }));
  };

const modalProps = {
    onSaveOrUpdate: beforeSubmitModal(dispatch(actions.insertOrEditCode.request())),
    onDelete: beforeSubmitModal(onDeleteCode),
  };
```

Comment: What is your expection on action function. How is it supposed to work. Does it use state values. Also are your states like `visible`, `selectedMenuItem` and `companyCodeModal` changed from anywhere else?

Comment: State changes elsewhere in the component.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use useEffect to do this

```
const [visible,setVisible] = useState(ture);

const doSomething = () => {
  setVisible(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
   //this will render every time the visible state changes
}, [visible]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to define the states in hooks

```
const [visible,setVisible]=useState(false) // initial value false
const [selectedMenuItem,setCompanyCodeModal]=useState(null) // initial value null
const [companyCodeModal,setCompanyCodeModal]=useState('')
```

you need when they change do some action

```
useEffect(()=> doSomething() ,[visible,selectedMenuItem,companyCodeModal])
```